# How to get Average Rating using SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

[image]

How can I calculate average rating for a tutor using T-SQL in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I think you should post some sample data. And your expected output. So everybody can help you better, my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, this should do it.

```
SELECT tutorid,
       CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN rated1 = 1 THEN 1.00 ELSE 0.00 END)+
       SUM(CASE WHEN rated2 = 1 THEN 2.00 ELSE 0.00 END)+
       SUM(CASE WHEN rated3 = 1 THEN 3.00 ELSE 0.00 END)+
       SUM(CASE WHEN rated4 = 1 THEN 4.00 ELSE 0.00 END)+
       SUM(CASE WHEN rated5 = 1 THEN 5.00 ELSE 0.00 END))/(COUNT (*))AS DECIMAL(3,2)) 'Average'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY tutorid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Query to find avg as:

```
SELECT        tutorid, (rated1 + rated2 + rated3 + rated4 + rated5) / 5.0 AS Average
FROM            tutor
```

Result for your demo data:

[image]